# Targeting Data in a .map with onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So I have the following code:

```
const test = (e) => {
  console.log('example:', e.target.item.attributes.dataIWant);
}

{records.map((item, index) => {

        return (
          <>
            <Accordion key={index}>
              <AccordionSummary  onClick={test(item)} expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />} aria-controls="panel1a-content" id="panel1a-header">
                <Typography>{item.attributes.name} {item.attributes.date}</Typography>
              </AccordionSummary>
            </Accordion>
          </>
        )
      })}
```

This is using react material UI, I have a collection of data in records, that I am mapping through. This creates and accordion panel that you can click to see accordion details.

When i click one of those panels, i want to grab a specific piece of data from the data set. Lets call it item.attributes.id

Generally i would assume to grab it with the event, to target that specific panels click/data set. But it doesn't seem to be working, just getting item is undefined.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: If your records have real ids, why are you using the array index as your key?

Comment: Additionally, that isn't how it works: the event target is the *DOM node* which doesn't have any of the data from the entity or even the React component. You could redefine test to `const test = (item) => (_e) => { console.log('example:', item.attributes.dataIWant) }` and everything should work. I'm actually not clear on how your code *is* working, since you are effectively passing `undefined` as a click handler....

Comment: @JaredSmith agree. Pass the function reference instead of the invoke.

Comment: Change `onClick={test(item)}` to `onClick={() => test(item)}`, and then you are passing the `item` for that particular instance and not the DOM event.  Avoids having to parse through the event entirely.  Then get rid of `e.target.` in your `test()`

Comment: Greg that worked, if you could right that in an answer, i can mark this as correct. The code i wrote was: onClick={() => test(item)}, and then test was:  const test = (item) => {
      console.log('mission number:', item.attributes.dataIWant);
    }

Answer (score 1):

When you wrote `onClick={test(item)}` I interpret that the return value of the `test()` function is assinged to the  `onClick` prop, during the component render.

During rendering, the function doesn't return anything explicitly (we get `undefined` implicitly). Therefore, your code becomes `onClick={undefined}`. But we want the test function to be executed, whenever the `<AccordianSummary/>` is clicked.

```
const test = (event, itemId) => {
  console.log(itemId);
}

{records.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <Accordion key={index}>
      <AccordionSummary
        onClick={(event) => test(event, item.attributes.id)}
        expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        aria-controls="panel1a-content"
        id="panel1a-header"
      >
        <Typography>{item.attributes.name} {item.attributes.date}</Typography>
      </AccordionSummary>
    </Accordion>
  )
})}
```

To achieve this expected output, a function reference has to be passed to `onClick`, that will be called later, and not during the rendering process. I'd suggest to user an arrow function

> `(event) => test(event, item.attributes.id)`

This arrow function will be invoked when the `<AccordianSummary/>` is clicked.

Answer (score -1):

The issue in your code lies in how you are invoking the test function in the onClick event handler. Currently, you are invoking the test function immediately when rendering the component instead of passing it as a callback function.

To fix this, you need to wrap the test function in an arrow function or a callback function to ensure it is called correctly when the onClick event occurs. Here's the modified code:

```
`const test = (e) => {
  console.log('example:', e.target.getAttribute('dataIWant'));
}

{records.map((item, index) => (
  <Accordion key={index}>
    <AccordionSummary
      onClick={(e) => test(e)}
      expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      aria-controls="panel1a-content"
      id="panel1a-header"
      dataIWant={item.attributes.id}
    >
      <Typography>{item.attributes.name} {item.attributes.date}</Typography>
    </AccordionSummary>
  </Accordion>
))}`
```

In the modified code, the onClick event handler is wrapped in an arrow function (e) => test(e). This ensures that the test function is only called when the onClick event occurs, with the event object e passed as an argument.

Additionally, the dataIWant attribute is added to the AccordionSummary component, and you can access it using `e.target.getAttribute('dataIWant')` in the test function.

By making these changes, you should be able to access the specific piece of data (item.attributes.id) from the dataset when clicking on the accordion panel.